# Не видит файл 404.php в теме Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, веб-программирование, cms, openserver

В общем я учу Wp по вот этому курсу(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=URFhyvZTENc&list=PL3LQJkGQtzc6Nwz67GGrMdqxim1c0H5DC&index=2) и при вводе несуществующего адреса меня перекидывало на стандартную браузерную страницу 404.Я вставил в .htaccess стандартный код(

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

и теперь переходит на основную страницу index.php.Но почему то полностью игнорируется файл 404.php почему так?
При этом если напрямую тыкнуть в этот файл то он откроется.

Comment: Отключи все плагин и включи дефолтную тему.

Comment: Все плагины отключены и я попробовал дефолтные темы,на них то же самое,просто не видит файл

Comment: @Captain_Obvious попробуйте зайти в Админ - Настройки - Постоянные ссылки сохранить настройки

Comment: Значит у тебя не аппач и потому хтацесс не работает